# Selected values as json_encode data

Tags: php, mysql, json

I've got two `foreach()` loops in my php to fetch MySQL data from 2 different dbs.

```
foreach ($result as $val) {
   $country = $val["count"]; //results fetched successfully
   $number = $val["tel"];
}

foreach ($rslt as $dta) {
   $score = $dta["score"]; //results fetched successfully
   $rank = $dta["rnk"];
}
```

I want to pass the results from both foreach loops as `json_encode()` data.
My question is, how do I pass `$number` , `$score` and `$rank`as `json_encode()`?

I tried the below at the bottom of the code, but did not work.

```
$data = array();
$data[$val] = $val["tel"];
$data[$dta] = $dta["score"];
$data[$dta] = $dta["rnk"];
echo json_encode($data);
```

Expecting output:

```
[{"tel":"123456","score":"785","rnk":"135"}]
```

Comment: Then what is wrong with it? Tell us the expected json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $val) {
   $data['tel'][] = $val["tel"];
   $country = $val["count"]; //results fetched successfully
   $number = $val["tel"];
}

foreach ($rslt as $dta) {
   $data['score'][] = $dta["score"];
   $data['rnk'][] = $dta["rnk"];
   $score = $dta["score"]; //results fetched successfully
   $rank = $dta["rnk"];
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Added an extra [] if array size of `$val["tel"],$dta["score"],$dta["rnk"]` is greater than 1 else you can remove [] if array size is 1

Comment: it brings only data in `$data['score'][] = $dta["score"];` and `   $data['rnk'][] = $dta["rnk"];`. This is missing -> `$data['tel'][] = $val["tel"];`

Comment: Please check if anything is coming in $val["tel"] variable. It should work with $val["tel"] too.

Answer (score 1):

`$dta` and `$val` are only in the loops scope. You assign variables within the loop, so use them.

```
$data = array();
$data['tel'] = $number;
$data['score'] = $score;
$data['rnk'] = $rank;
echo json_encode($data);
```

You can also assign $data within your foreach loop.

```
$data = array();

foreach ($result as $val) {
   $data['country'] = $val["count"]; //results fetched successfully
   $data['tel'] = $val["tel"];
}

foreach ($rslt as $dta) {
   $data['score']= $dta["score"]; //results fetched successfully
   $data['rank'] = $dta["rnk"];
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Is it possible to put `$data[]` inside each foreach loop and get the same output? Like what @mohit is trying to achieve?

Comment: yes, edited. consider upvoting at least, if it helped. regards.